# The descriptor object returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I want to refer to the descX and descY but it return undefined..

```
var polar = {
  x: undefined,
  y: undefined,
  
  descX: Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, "x", {
    value: 3,
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    set setX(val) {
      polar.x = val;
    }
  }),
    
  descY: Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, "y", {
      value: 4,
      writable: true,
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      set setY(val) {
        polar.y = val;
      }
  }),
}
```

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) + [mcve]